# Will Microsoft Edge support COM automation (InternetExplorer object)?

Tags: internet-explorer, com, microsoft-edge

The last several versions of Internet Explorer have allowed a Windows desktop (classic) application to control IE (to some extent) [via COM automation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa752084). Will this type of automation also be available in Microsoft Edge? If so, will the Methods, Properties and Events be the same?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Microsoft Edge will not support the COM automation interface (InternetExplorer object) that you referred to.

For automation scenarios, our direction is to support of the WebDriver interface that is supported across browsers. WebDriver support is [now available](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/) in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 and requires a separate executable that [you can download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212).

To get an idea of capabilities, you can refer to the [Microsoft Edge WebDriver page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) which will be kept up-to-date with the latest WebDriver commands available.

Comment: Edge WebDriver status page returns now a 404.
Maybe it is now https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ ?

Comment: @Luke — this does appear to be a better link so updated the answer; the link includes information on the new Chromium-based Microsoft Edge as well as "Microsoft Edge Legacy".