# Switching from Internet Explorer to Microsoft Edge

Tags: vba, excel, microsoft-edge

After the recent release of Windows 10, including the new browser - Microsoft Edge - would anyone simply know how to open Microsoft Edge browser via Excel VBA. I have tried searching the website without any luck.

This is the current basic Excel VBA coding I use to open the Internet Explorer:

```
Sub xyz()

Dim Browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'Microsoft Internet Controls
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim URL As String

  URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news"
  Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
    Browser.Silent = True
    Browser.navigate URL
    Browser.Visible = True
  Do
    Loop Until Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set HTMLdoc = Browser.document

End Sub
```

This is a very straight forward piece of VBA coding to open the BBC website for example.

However, what is the new piece of coding to open Microsoft Edge?

Comment: This does much more than open,, it fetches the DOM of the opened page as a scriptable object, is that what you want to do? If you just want to open a URL and forget about it you can shellexecute `microsoft-edge:http://acme.com`

Comment: Thank you Alex, I think and believe this is only alternative solution to use Microsoft Edge by Shell Execute for the time being.  However, I do not know much about Shell Execute programming, so please can you provide an example?  Much appreciated and thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object

Answer (score 1):

According to MS [here](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/faq/testing), IE11 ships with Windows 10

> The default browser for Windows 10 is Microsoft Edge, which is powered by our new rendering engine and is our path forward for the Web on Windows. Site developers should focus their testing on Microsoft Edge for new and existing experiences. Internet Explorer 11 will be included for some legacy scenarios and users will be have the option to choose it as the default browser, like with any other browser.

So existing code for IE should continue to work. Not tried it though.

Some technical stuff on Edge can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772401(v=vs.85).aspx)

As of Mon 10-Aug-2015, I have upgraded one PC from Win 7 Pro SP1 to Win 10 Pro and the code you supplied works fine. IE11 runs fine and shows the website. The [IE11 download page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/download-ie) confirms that I've already got it installed.

Comment: Thank you ChipsLetten, I have decided to go along with Alex K's suggestion to open Microsoft Edge via Shell Execution for the short term - see above.

Comment: I'm running [tag:windows-10] and any reference to `InternetExplorer.Application` throws an error stating the ActiveX object cannot be created - so I don't think this is the case.

Comment: In my installation of Win10 Pro, IE 11 shows up as a "Windows feature" in Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off. Might be worth checking to see if you need to check the box to install it.

Comment: @ChipsLetten Interestingly, I opened IE11 from the start menu and since then the `InternetExporer.Application` object works fine. Perhaps it isn't fully 'installed' until you run it for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue upon updating to Windows 10. Turns out 'Microsoft Internet Controls' and 'Microsoft HTML Object Library' had been "removed" from 'References'. Adding them resolved the problem and code worked fine without requiring any alterations. Don't know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer but it worked for me.

The Internet Explorer object will still open through VBA in Windows 10 using IE11.  However, I had to ask Cortana to open IE11 first so it would sort out all of it's "first time use" pop-ups and what not.  "Welcome to IE11" and "Let's get started" etc.

Once I got through all that and closed the browser.  I re-ran my macro and the browser object came up fine and worked as normal.  Hope this helps someone.

P.S. I'm using the CreateObject method of creating the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

> how to open Microsoft Edge browser via Excel VBA

VBS/VBA uses the COM object model (ActiveX) to communicate with desktop processes and this feature will not be made available for Edge.

Fortunately newer cross-browser solutions (i.e. WebDriver) exist for automation and Edge adopts these new standards. Unfortunately, to use them, the techniques used will need to change.

Duplicate of [Will Microsoft Edge support COM automation (InternetExplorer object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object).