# Is it possible to create and use a Microsoft Edge variable / object in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have some VBA code that pulls stock prices from the web. My code uses an InternetExplorer object / document to do so. However, if possible, I would like to use a Microsoft Edge object / document instead.

In my current code:

1. I initialize an InternetExplorer variable: `Dim ie As InternetExplorer`
2. Then I create an object: `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a Microsoft Edge instead of Internet Explorer object / document in my code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Begin here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will Microsoft Edge support COM automation (InternetExplorer object)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Edge doesn't have an API VBA can use.

IE will continue to work.

Sources:

[MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/148d9639-0747-41bc-82b5-1469ff5bd1b5/excel-vba-coding-switching-from-internet-explorer-to-microsoft-edge?forum=iewebdevelopment)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784247/switching-from-internet-explorer-to-microsoft-edge)

Comment: If you want to have VBA capability to automate Microsoft Edge, please take the opportunity to upvote this issue on the MS development site and bring it to their attention: 

https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/38614222-vba-capability-to-automate-microsoft-edge

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub OpenEdge()

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Correction to the answer by destination-data:

IE will continue to work **unless** you actually uninstall it using windows features. Which was the case for one of my clients and the code that used
`Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`
broke. Be aware!

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. What Windows features are you referring to?

Comment: I meant that in Windows 10 one can uninstall internet explorer using "Turn windows features on or off" dialog - therefore there is no guarantee that IE is available on a client machine.