# How is it possible to change a VBA program to run from internet explorer to microsoft edge?

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, ms-office

Here is a piece of code i wrote.

```
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'microsoft internet controls (shdocvw.dll)
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim the_input_elements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim input_element As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim IeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ie As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ie3 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Dont forget to remove this
Dim ie2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'To remove
Dim input_element2 As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim the_input_elements2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim objShell As Object 'CHECK MAYBE HERE IS THE ERROR. CHANGE FROM OBJECT TO SHELL??
Dim IE_count As Variant
Dim objShell3 As Object
Dim objShell2 As Object 'Dont forget to remove this at the end.
Dim my_url As Variant
Dim my_title As Variant 'Tp remove
Dim my_title2 As Variant 'To remove
Dim my_title3 As Variant 'To remove
Dim x As Variant
Dim element As HTMLObjectElement

 Sub Press_Button1()
 Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With objIE
    .Navigate "microsoft-edge:https://www.ndexsystems.com/fengine/fullservice/en/kerrfinancialsalogin.go?fromLogoff=true" ' Main page

    .Visible = 1
    'Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
```

Is there a way to switch all this code from running on internet explorer to microsoft edge? I have no problem changing the data types of the variables i declared above.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create and use a Microsoft Edge variable / object in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636368/is-it-possible-to-create-and-use-a-microsoft-edge-variable-object-in-vba)

Answer (score 1):

There is neither ActiveX or COM support in Edge. It doesn't have an API VBA can use.

Because of security reasons, Microsoft removes the support for ActiveX controls in MS Edge. I suggest you check for Web Driver. WebDriver is a remote control interface that enables introspection and control of user agents. It provides a platform- and language-neutral wire protocol as a way for out-of-process programs to remotely instruct the behavior of web browsers. See [WebDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver) and [Bringing automated testing to Microsoft Edge through WebDriver](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/).