# How to Access and interact with a website through VBA (post IE)?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a contact clean-up application for excel. I am looking for a way for the macro to open a webpage in the background, enter information into it, extract the result, and then paste it into the spreadsheet. Specifically, the current use case is checking if a given e-mail is valid, but there will be more uses throughout the program. First I tried using

```
Sub Hi()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
With IE
.Navigate "http://www.google.com"
End With
End Sub
```

This was just a starter test to send the browser to google. This gave me a Run-Time Error 429: ActiveX Component Can't create object. I'm assuming this is because InternetExplorer no longer really exists, but I did not see an alternate for microsoft edge. I then tried

```
shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url http:google.com")
```

This successfully opens the page, but I can't seem to figure out how to edit it from here. The internet hasn't given me any leads, which makes me wonder whether it's even possible. Alternatively, is there a way to create and launch a program in a different language from within the excel macro, a language that is able to interact with websites?

I've heard about some plug-ins and add-ins that might help, but plug-ins and the like are a no-go. Since I'm sending this to my less tech savvy coworkers, I need to be able to make this macro in such a way that they just have to download the xlsm file once and not have to mess with anything, since they are not technologically inclined.

Are either of these options possible? Ideally the first one being possible would be better, as I only know VBA code so it'd be a lot of extra work to figure out how to do this all in a different language, but the second option would certainly be appreciated as well.

Comment: The best method of accomplishing what you want will depend greatly on what the **actual url** of your destination is and how you post information to receive the target workbook for download.

Comment: That is the problem, I'm using this on a number of different websites. First there is the e-mail checker, then there is a phone number checker, then there is our online client database, then there is a subscription list from our website, and those are just the ones I can think of off the top of my head, there are likely a few more as well, which is why I worry that a use-case-specific solution will leave me asking for 10 more use-case-specific solutions each time it comes up.

Comment: please change `Access` to `access` in the title because `Access` is a microsoft database application

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object