# close microsoft edge tab from powershell script

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I am using below powershell script to open a webpage using microsoft edge.
start microsoft-edge:https://stackoverflow.com

I need to close the same using powershell. I have a piece of code that will work for IE but need the similar for edge.

```
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com' 

Function Close-IETab {
param($url)

    $oWindows = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows

    foreach ($oWindow in $oWindows.Invoke()) {

        if ($oWindow.Fullname -match "IEXPLORE.EXE" -and $oWindow.LocationURL -eq $url) {

            Write-verbose "Closing tab $($oWindow.LocationURL)"
            $oWindow.Quit()
        }
    }

}

try
{
Close-IETab($url )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Edge browser cannot be automated like the IE browser. It does not support this kind of automation.

I suggest you try to use a selenium web driver to automate the MS Edge browser.

It is the best suitable approach to automate the Edge browser.

[Microsoft web driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

Reference:

[Will Microsoft Edge support COM automation (InternetExplorer object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object)