# Upgrading From IE to EDGE

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-edge, getelementbyid

I need VBA Code translation for Edge.
I’m in a Window10/Excel 16 environment. I have been using Internet Explorer (IE) when I **scrape** data from websites.
Now, I am needing to upgrade to Microsoft Edge. I am having to translate some code and I am finding I need some help.

I used to call the URL https://www.azblue.com/individualsandfamilies/ using “IE.navigate”. Ex:

```
IE.navigate "https://www.azblue.com/individualsandfamilies/"
```

But, what I cannot figure out is how to use these other lines of Code with Edge. Here are a 3  lines of code (disjointed) that I use often and need to know the syntax translation for Edge:

```
IE.document.getElementById("lockedcontent_0_maincolumn_2_twocolumn2fb4d204091d44aa08196ef423877fd9f_0_ToolbarUsernameControl").Focus

IE.document.getElementById("lockedcontent_0_maincolumn_2_twocolumn2fb4d204091d44aa08196ef423877fd9f_0_ToolbarUsernameControl").Value = "MyUserName" 

IE.document.Focus
```

Of course, any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Edge browser doesn't support the COM automation interface that used in VBA. If you want to automate Microsoft Edge, you should use [WebDriver](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/).

> To get started using WebDriver, you will need to download a testing framework of your choice along with an appropriate language binding and the MicrosoftWebDriver server.

We usually use Selenium and you could download the language binding in [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/). At the same time, you could download Microsof Edge WebDriver in [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

Reference link: [Will Microsoft Edge support COM automation (InternetExplorer object)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object)