# Download Java x64 and Microsoft Edge with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

I found this script to download Javax64 and it really works, but I had some problems.

The first is that the command I would put would be inside an XML file that a powershell script calls it, so putting it directly like this, it gave some errors because where it shows "<a" the XML understood that this was part of it and not of something that only PowerShell would make use of.

The second is "New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application" where this is not working on my Windows Server and it is recommended not to use it for ie it is being discontinued soon. It still works on Windows 10 normally but on Windows Server it gets stuck in a loop and won't get out.

How would I convert this script to an Invoke-WebRequest, is this possible? Because then I would just need to put the complete string of the Invoke-WebResquest in my XML file and PowerShell would read it normally, I think.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
# Navigate to the requested page
$ie.Navigate2("https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp")

$anchor = $null
while($anchor -eq $null -or $anchor -eq "")
{
     #wait 1 second for the page to load
     start-sleep -m 1000
     #get the html of the page
     $html = $ie.document.body.innerHTML
     #apply your regex to identify the anchar with the download link
     $anchor = [regex]::Match($html, '(?:<a title="Download Java software for Windows \(64-bit\)" href=")(.*)(?:">)').Groups[1] .Value
}

#regex doesn't return the link correctly, that's why I made the substring to get the link
$url_download = $anchor.Substring(0,$anchor.IndexOf(""""))
$url_download
```

Edit: There is the same situation but to download Edge?

Comment: Look into using a package manager instead. I recommend Chocolatey, this saves us so much time in our environment and it's not hard to create your own packages if the need arises. You can install Oracle Java and MS edge with it easily: `choco install -y microsoft-edge oraclejdk` (there are also jre8 and jre6 for older versions of the runtime only, and openjdk packages if you need to avoid java licensing).

Comment: I use it in another environment, but I really need to make the download work via powershell because the automation of this is for SCCM. And I can't install Chocolatey in that environment.

Comment: Why not look at the package source and see how their `chocolateyInstall.ps1` does it? Oracle likes to make downloading their software through automation difficult, so either the package must use a direct URL or knows how to set other data in the web request (e.g. referrer) for Oracle's servers to allow the download.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** Neither `Invoke-WebRequest` or the built-in .NET clients for obtaining files over HTTP seem to support rendering the full DOM, and so JavaScript cannot be executed. JavaScript is required to access those downloads links and use the site in general. You have two choices:
>
> 1. Use static links as I have outlined in my original answer below; or
> 2. Automate Edge using [WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/), which is how Microsoft recommends you automate MS Edge. [There is no COM functionality for controlling the Edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31306444/584676).
>
> Unfortunately, I cannot help with the latter as I have no experience using **WebDriver**.

Looking at the [oraclejdk](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/oraclejdk#files) Chocolatey package installation script, the URL is
`https://download.oracle.com/java/17/archive/jdk-17.0.2_windows-x64_bin.msi`. Since you're already familiar with Chocolatey from another environment, I would figure the version you need, see if there is a Chocolatey package for it, and get the direct URL from that package version's installation script.

You could also attempt to templatize the URL like so:

`https://download.oracle.com/java/MAJOR_VERSION/archive/jdk-MAJOR_VERSION.MINOR_VERSION.PATCH_windows-x64_bin.msi`

where `MAJOR_VERSION`, `MINOR_VERSION`, and `PATCH` are pieces of the Java version. However, I have not tested that all Java MSI URLs follow this pattern.

---

Regardless, once you have the URL, it's as simple as:

```
# Work around performance issue with iwr and the progress bar
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$MSI_URL = 'https://download.oracle.com/java/17/archive/jdk-17.0.2_windows-x64_bin.msi'
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing $MSI_URL -Outfile 'jdk-17.0.2_windows-x64_bin.msi'
```

Comment: Oh, we have some problems. The first is that the java I'm downloading is the Runtime I think, this one is for development, otherwise I'm wrong, while the download link is static for each version, that is, when there's a new version, I'll have to update manually. While in the example I put up there, it does an html push and searches for the string that contains Download Java software for Windows (64-bit)...

Comment: ...then it breaks the unnecessary lines, leaving only the real link, and this command is dynamic , whenever there is a new version, it will capture again. The only inconvenience is that it was made using New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application" and it is not working on Windows Server (and it makes sense since ie must be discontinued by Microsoft) if there was a way to change ie to edge or turning into Invoke-WebRequest would be perfect.

Comment: So find a JRE link (there are also choco packages) and use that with Invoke-WebRequest instead. Yes you will need to change urls on new versions, Java does not have a "latest" download URL outside of crawling the web page. This is one of the pains of opting not to use package management. Not all vendors include easy to consume "latest" links. You can always use Chocolatey through SCCM (we do).

Comment: The jdk includes the runtime and I only used it as an example. Find one of the JRE packages instead and you might be able to craft a link from that. But essentially what you're asking for is for someone to write a parser for the Java downloads page for you that doesn't make use of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not an SCCM admin to be able to implement Choco within it, but using a utility called CMPackager I can convince them to implement it. Conversion to Invoke-WebResquest is possible, but as I don't know that much about scripting, it's kind of complicated to build it, although I keep trying for several hours to do this conversion.

Comment: My comments around downloads for https://www.java.com not working from .NET are irrelevant, and I have removed them. See my note in my updated answer. If you think WebDriver is the right solution for you, I recommend doing some research on WebDriver yourself and ask any relevant new questions on this site, rather than repurposing this question.

Comment: Hello, well, i researched about how to create a deployment link for java8 and i found a script that capture a download link a lot of the packages like edge, firefox, chrome and java. After reeading the documentation, i got it to implement inside another script (CMPackager) for download and deploy the packages automatically in SCCM. Anyway, thank you so much for your help friend.

Comment: The only inconvenience is the Bizagi Modeler package, that script don't have in your list for capture and create a download link, but, is normal because the Bizagi Modeler need a credential for download the package. In the older days you can download the package without create a login but now, you need create a login and confirm your account for download the package even though package is free.