# Changing browser from internet explorer to Microsoft edge in VBA script

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I have a code where I open an URL in "Internet Explore" using the following piece of code.

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL
```

now I changed it to as follows

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("MSEdge.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL
```

and  I ran into "run time error '429' ActiveX component can't create a object" at the following line

```
Set IE = CreateObject("MSEdge.Application")
```

I tried to fix it but ran into a dead end, can someone help me to fix the error?

I am expecting to open an url in Microsoft edge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302304/will-microsoft-edge-support-com-automation-internetexplorer-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Edge does not support the COM automation interface so you won't be able to use the traditional VBA way to automate Microsoft Edge. To automate Microsoft Edge, normally you can:

1. Use SeleniumBasic if you need to stick to VBA. You can refer to [this accepted answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/843285/edge-opening-and-filling-a-webpage-through-vba) as an example.
2. [Move to Selenium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp#using-selenium-4) if you are willing to switch to other languages, which keeps receiving updates to support modern browsers better.